# Proof with pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I have a set $A={1,3,5,7,...,153,155}$, and $S\subset A$ so that $|S|=22$.

I have to prove that it is possible to choose 4 different subsets of size 2 in S, so that they have the same absolute difference.

Comment: Very good. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @uniquesolution I thought about dividing A into subsets with the same difference e.g difference of 2: {1+4i, 3+4i} where i is between 0 and 38 (this would give 39 subsets). Or another way to choose would be {{1+12i, 7+12i}, {3+12i, 9+12i}, {5+12i, 11+12i}} - difference 6, and i between 0 and 12, but as I understand I'll need to do the same but so that I get an i between 0 and 4, and I can't think of a situation like that.

Comment: @Parasect  Consider [editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3489927/edit) your question to include your previous comments as it shows your effort . This way , people are more likely to notice your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $231$ subsets of size $2$ in $S$. The difference between the two elements of a pair is an even number between $2$ and $154$, so there are $77$ possibilities.

Suppose for a contradiction that for each of the $77$ possibilities for the difference there are at most $3$ subsets of $S$ of size $2$ with that difference. Then there would be exactly $3$ subsets of size $2$ with that difference, since $231 = 77\cdot 3$. So there are three subsets with difference $154$. But this is a contradiction, since the only subset with difference $154$ is $\{155,1\}$.